# UnitTesting a function that reads a text file and returns a dict

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I want to unit test this function. It opens a file from disk, but I would like the unit test to not rely on external data, and be totally decoupled from the file system.

```
def instrument_map(map_filename='Instruments.txt'):
    """Maps instrument prefix to filename"""
    with open(map_filename) as f:
        return dict(line.rstrip().split(' ', 1) for line in f)
```

I've read about mocking and `StringIO`, but are not able figure out how to go about implementing either of these. Which would be the better approach, and where to start?

The contents of `Instruments.txt` looks like this:

> 00 Score
>      01 SopranoCn
>      02 SoloCn

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provide any code that you tried, it's hard to guess what's your problem is.

If you don;t know where to start, then take a look at the `mock_open` and `patch` functions from `mock` library:

```
>>> from mock import mock_open, patch
```

these 2 functions should help you mock your function.